# Redirect from UIViewController to another UIViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Can you help with redirect from one UIViewController to another? I have 2 x UIViewController(ViewController and OverViewController). I have a no idea how can I redirect from ViewController to OverViewController. I tried `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OverViewController" sender:nil];`

But it show me only error 
`Receiver (<ViewController: 0x7b73b350>) has no segue with identifier 'OverViewController'`
I set storyboard id to OverViewController

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call `performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:` you indeed need a segue connected between the ViewControllers. Try one of the following:

1. ctrl+drag from the button to the destination ViewController and create a push segue. This will save you the trouble of calling `performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:` programatically and will work.
2. ctrl+drag from your ViewController to your 'OverViewController' destination VC and you'll see a new segue created for you. Go to this segue 'Attribute Inspector' (3rd tab) and assign it your @"OverViewController" identifier. Then, the call to `performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:` will work as there exist a segue with this identifier now.

Comment: Okej and than how can I redirect without ctrl+drag method?

Answer (score 3):

It is working for me.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OverViewController"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Yes this work but animation will be like modal but if you want to be like push you must youse preparefromSegueIndentifier.